# How to get furniture models from 3d.io into ARKit

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, arkit, archilogic, 3d.io

I'm displaying furniture from [furniture.3d.io](https://furniture.3d.io) in my AR app, which works well in a web view using Google's [WebARonARKit](https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARKit) and aframe. However the tracking and lighting seems to be better when using ARKit natively.

ARKit requires models to be either .scn, .dae, or .obj formats. Is there any way to export the furniture from [3d.io](https://3d.io) so that I can use it in my app? Aframe has a gltf exporter that I could use, so I might try to manually convert a few models using from 3d.io -> .gltf -> .dae and blender, but can't figure out how to do it in a more automated way.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you go from 3d.io -> .blend -> export .dae for any model that you wish to take to ARKit. Blender has a great collada exporter.

I'm not sure if exporting furniture / any 3d object is possible yet from 3d.io, but it should be possible from archilogic.com. You can also directly export collada files from archilogic, but texture export is not yet supported.

Edit: actually archilogic now exports diffuse, normal and specular maps for collada